# Cannot find the database file in windows application

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, windows-phone-7

I have an Windows mobile application which internally uses `SQLLite Mango` for Database Connections.

Now, I have this code which creates a new database.

```
using (EtsDataContext context = new EtsDataContext(Con_String))
{
   if (!context.DatabaseExists())
   {
        context.CreateDatabase();
   }
}
```

The problem is that I cannot find a `.sdf` file anywhere in my project. I even searched the full drive but could not find any.

Where I can find this `.sdf` file ? (I can see the values added are displayed throughout the life time of application.)

Answer (score 1):

It's a possibility that file is hidden. To toggle between viewing hidden files and not hidden files do this **on Windows 8**.

1. Open a folde > single-click on the View tab >  put a check mark in
   the checkbox Hidden items

[Hidden files Windows 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtDKj.jpg)

**On windows 7:**

1. Open Folder Options by clicking the Start button Picture of the
   Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking Appearance and
   Personalization, and then clicking Folder Options.
2. Click the View tab.
3. Under Advanced settings, click Show hidden files and folders, and
       then click OK.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/show-hidden-files#show-hidden-files=windows-vista